# CASL Canadian SPAM Law Question - I am an individual seeking a job, can I mass email a video intro of myself to recruiters asking to connect

Tags: internet, spam

I find Canadian SPAM law confusing, I am an individual seeking a job, so can I mass email a video intro of myself to recruiters asking to connect?  The email is clear, that I want a networking opportunity and am seeking a new position.  I want to email 3000 contacts in US and Canada - my LinkedIn and a video resume.  Is this legal?  Essentially creating a connection for future consideration from a job they may have or know of a fit somewhere else. etc etc.

Comment: Even if it _was_ legal (which I don't know), I don't think spamming will increase your reputation. Many companies are eagerly looking to hire, so better work on your skills and update your linkedin profile accordingly.

Comment: If you have a LinkedIn account and aren't already receiving 3000 messages a week from recruiters there is something seriously wrong with your profile. Emailing them a link to your LinkedIn won't help.

Answer (score 1):

### The [CAN-SPAM](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/E-1.6/page-1.html#h-176975) law is not about mass emails, it’s about any form of electronic message

It prohibits sending any “commercial electronic message” unless you have consent and, if you do, it must contain the required information about you and a way to avoid future contact (unsubscribe).

Based on the definition in the act a job application is probably commercial particularly since there is a specific carve out for communication about existing employment relationships.

It doesn’t matter if you send 1 or 3,000 commercial electronic messages, the law applies.

So, for your use case, it would be wise to comply with the law - have permission and provide the required information and opt-out mechanism.